# Next.Js serverless functions are not working unless I ping them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, webhooks, serverless

I have an endpoint which getting messages from whatsapp webhook.
This endpoint then calls async to another endpoint and returns 200 to the whatsapp webhook.

In my local machine this works perfectly and fast, but in my deployment project in vercel it gets only to the first endpoint but then only if I ping the endpoint then it gets triggered by the last call.

I tried to add some logs but debugging in vercel production is hard and not very effective.
this is i call my other endpoints
this is my whatsapp webhook.ts

```
        const conversation = await prisma.conversation.findFirst({
          where: {
            senderId: message.senderId,
          },
        });
        console.log(
          `${process.env.BASE_URL}/api/whatsapp/services/preValidation`
        );

        if (!conversation?.verify || !conversation) {
          console.log("member is not verified yet");
          axios.post(
            `${process.env.BASE_URL}/api/whatsapp/services/preValidation`,
            {
              conversation: conversation,
              message: message,
              recipientId: teamId,
              source: "whatsapp",
            }
          );
          return new Response("message is not verified yet", {
            status: 200,
          });
        }

        axios.post(
          `${process.env.BASE_URL}/api/facebook/services/handleMessages`,
          {
            conversation: conversation,
            message: message,
            recipientId: teamId,
          }
        );
return new Response("EVENT_RECEIVED", { status: 200 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. The main problem is the difference between our local dev env and the Vercel platform. In our locals, the Axios calls get resolved even after we have sent the response. In Vercel serverless functions or edge functions, all the background tasks are terminated once a response is returned unless you're streaming the response or using a function like https://vercel.com/docs/functions/edge-functions/edge-functions-api#waituntil; that is why you can't see the logs.

If you add `await` before your Axios calls, everything should work as expected.

For reference:

- [[nodejs] Behavior of Vercel after using res.send()](https://github.com/vercel/vercel/discussions/4949)
- [Can I fire and forget an async function inside a serverless function?](https://github.com/orgs/vercel/discussions/3500)
- [Is it possible to run an async function AFTER the response has been
  sent?](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/14077)